# Android 2.1 (API level 7) and AdMob Sdk 6.3.1

Tags: android, sdk, admob

Im trying to compile an andriod app API level 7 with Admob Sdk 6.3.1 but Im get an error related to

```
"android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">"
```

I googled it and learnt that I've to compile against Android 3.2 and set SDK Min to 13. But that way my app will not be compatible with Android 2.1, am I correct? Is there any workaround? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can compile against a higher level, but still support lower SDK levels. Per the [Admob Documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/):

> The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set `android:minSdkVersion` to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum).

Comment: @ramires.cabral - if this answers your question, please feel free to accept the answer. Thanks and best of luck going forward!